# Angular2 RC4 Unit Test Service

Tags: angular

#### The Service

```
@Injectable()

export class NavService {

    constructor (
        public pagesToLoad
    ) {
        this.pagesToLoad = [1,2,3,4,5]
    }

    public lookAround(currentPage){
        let tuple = (this.pagesToLoad.indexOf(currentPage)-1,this.pagesToLoad.indexOf(currentPage)+1)
        return tuple
    }
```

#### The Test

```
import {Modal, Alert, NavParams, ViewController, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import {provide,ReflectiveInjector,Component,PLATFORM_PIPES} from '@angular/core'
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { getDOM } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter';
import {
  TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
}  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  xit, 
  xdescribe,
  ComponentFixture, 
  inject,
  async,
  setBaseTestProviders,
  TestComponentBuilder
} from '@angular/core/testing'
 import {NavService} from './nav-service';

let tcb;
let navService;

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provide(navService, {useClass: NavService})
]);

beforeEach(inject(
        [
            TestComponentBuilder,
            NavService
        ], 
        (
            _tcb,
            _navService
        ) => { 
            tcb         = _tcb
            navService  = _navService

    }));

describe('NavService', () => {

    it ('should have instantiated nav service', () => {
        expect(this.navService instanceof NavService).toBeTruthy()
     })
})
```

#### The Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookAround' of undefined
```

Should be pretty straight forward, yet my test fails. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Of course I didn't had to provide dependencies when directly testing the Service. So this works simply like this:

```
import {NavService} from './nav-service'

describe('NavService', () => {

    it ('should have instantiated nav service', () => {
        let navService = new NavService();
        expect(navService.lookAround(3)).toEqual((2,4))
     })
})
```

> Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.3): Executed 1 of 4 (skipped 3) SUCCESS (0.013 secs / 0.005 secs)